# facebook connect api

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to use the facebook connect api to just grab some information and use it with a customized form?
Because facebook register api shows a pre-filled form, how to get these data and use them with another form
Thanks

Comment: Yes it's possible, I do it on my site. You can do it through the graph api: http://graph.facebook.com/userid/name. See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the Facebook PHP SDK ([see on github](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)). Here is how you would do that.

```
require "facebook.php";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '...',
    'secret' => '...',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

Here, if `$user` is not null, the user is logged in and you have his personal data in the array `$user_profile`.

Here is an example of the form you can generate pre-filled with some Facebook data :

```
<?php if ($user): ?>
    <form action="#" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $user_profile['name'] ?>">
        <input type="submit" value="Continue &rarr;">
    </form>
    <a href="<?php echo $facebook->getLogoutUrl() ?>">Logout of Facebook</a>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $facebook->getLoginUrl() ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
<?php endif ?>
```

See [the example of the Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) for more detail on the flow.

Comment: thanks for the idea but when I implemented it an changed the appID and te secret, it worked but something like an error is shown (Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /PATH/TO/SITE/index.php:2) in /PATH/TO/SITE/facebook.php on line 38)

Comment: It is because you made the `require "facebook.php"` after having executed some code (in your `index.php`, line 2). You should put the require statement at the very beginning of your flow, before everything else is done.

Comment: Would I be correct in saying that the above code only works if the user has already authorised your app?

Comment: No, it works even if he has not already authorized the app. When he clicks on the login button, if he has not authorized the app already, Facebook will ask him the authorization (if he is logged in Facebook).